# Why Substituting the Generator point in Elliptic Curve SECP256k1 not satisfying the Curve Equation over the finite field?

Tags: cryptography

I'm beginning to understand Elliptic Curve Cryptography. I was in the middle of writing a C++ class to do Elliptic Curve Operations like Point Addition, Point Doubling & Scalar Multiplication. It uses GMPLIB to do Big Integer Operations over finite field. I've only scratched the surface of mathematics Of Elliptic Curves. But my C++ class successfully does all the Operations for Cryptography for small curves, but it gets stuck when the values Of curves given by SECP Standard are substituted (SECP256k1).

My C++ class automatically verifies whether a point lies on curve or not. It says the Generator point does not lie on the SECP curve.

**EDIT** : Thankyou everyone for your support !!! :) I got the Application running and successfully doing point addition and scalar multiplication and it's able to do encryption and decryption !!! :) 
BUT Still For Only SECP Curves it stays Generator point does not lie on curve !!! 
I commented out this code and it works perfectly : 
This is the code that checks for point validity and causing the problem :

```
bool IsValidPoint()
    {
        if ((Square(y) % curve.p) == ((Cube(x) + (curve.a) * x + (curve.b))%curve.p ))
        {
                return true;
         }
            /***Error : returns false !!! ***/
            /* curve.p is the proven prime , a, b have their usual  meanings
 n is the order of the curve 'x' is the variable in the equation y^2 = x^3 + ax +b where a = 0,  b =7 (for SECP256k1)       */
            return false;
    }
```

**EDIT2** : Simple Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
      mpz_class a = mpz_class("0");
      mpz_class b = mpz_class("7");
     mpz_class Gx= mpz_class("55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240");
     mpz_class Gy= mpz_class("32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424");
     mpz_class p= mpz_class("115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337");
     cout << (((Gx * Gx * Gx)+a*Gx+b) -  (Gy * Gy )) % p << endl;
     //cout << ((Gx * Gx * Gx)+a*Gx+b) % p << endl;
      return 0;
}
```

Thankyou very much !!! Every help is appreciated !!!:) :) :)

Comment: We can't help you with your code without seeing it. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: each curve has a specific G

Comment: Thankyou Mat and Woodstock for your help !!! :) Please see my edits !!! I'm new to Stack Overflow and I didn't knew how to format code for it !!! But I downloaded the app and I think it's absolutely amazing !!! :) :) :)

Comment: @Mat : Thankyou, Please see my edits !!!

Comment: Please show the **complete** code - e.g. a complete program that somebody could compile and run without having to guess at how to fill in what's missing (main function, etc).

Comment: In particular, I am wondering: (1) are you using types that do arbitrary-precision arithmetic correctly?  (2) are your `Square` and `Cube` functions correct?  (3) are you actually using the right values for `x` and `y` and `curve`?

Comment: @NateEldredge : Yes absolutely !!! The real application is 1000+ lines of code!!!   I'm using GMPLIB to do Square , Cube Multiply !!! Thankyou so much for considering my question !!! :)

Comment: Then, please cut it down to a small but complete program that just evaluates whether the point satisfies the equation.  This should not need to be more than a couple dozen lines.

Comment: @NateEldredge : See my edits please ... It should output zero, if (Gx, Gy) lies on the curve,  but it's not !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for `p` is wrong.  According to [the standard](http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf) it should be

`FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE FFFFFC2F`

which in decimal is

`115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663`

Changing your code to use the correct value of `p`, I get the expected output of `0`.  The point is indeed on the curve.

Comment: Thankyou So Much for your answer !!! You found an error that escaped my eyes for over 3 days. I was converting the values from hex to decimal online and have mistakingly put both the order n and the prime P to be the same !!! My Code works perfectly right now !!! Thankyou so much !!! :) :) :) BTW, out of curiosity is the cofactor of the curve truncated to 1 ??? Sorry for my mistake, I am fascinated about Cryptography !!! I learned the basics of ECC from YouTube videos !!! And I'm so elated that everything works flawlessly now!!! May God Bless You !!! :) :) :)

Comment: I understood that Co factor perfectly equalling 1 is only ideal !!! Actually cofactor here is : 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000037344553450401341527595825479805550940193115084298802686998283 Thankyou So much !!! Your answer opened so much insights for me !!! Thankyou for spending your valuable time for this !!! I thought ideal curves are possible in the mathematical abstract world !!! I'm not a mathematics expert, and I really don't know the depth of the math of elliptic curves !!! Can you please suggest books / starting points for my research as a beginner ??? :)

Comment: Also as a side note I realise that all the equations for ECC are modulo prime but during the calculations I noticed there are negative slopes and negative coordinates (that surely satisfy the curve equation) come up during the intermediate steps of the calculations like Point Addition, Doubling etc. Is this allowable according to the rules of finite field algebra !!! ??? Also, such processes are silent and hence unnoticed unless I log them !!! ??? Please do correct me if I'm wrong ! :) :) :) BUT Still the cryptographic processes run flawlessly despite all that !!! Thankyou so much!!! ☺☺☺

Comment: The cofactor is the order of the curve (i.e. the number n) divided by the order of the point (i.e. the number of times it must be added to itself to yield the identity).  By Lagrange's theorem it has to be exactly an integer, and the fact that it is 1 here is exactly the statement that G is a generator of the group, i.e. the order of the point is exactly equal to n.  If you do not find that they are equal, then something is wrong with your calculation.  You should use integer division instead of floating point in such cases, since floating point is not perfectly accurate.

Comment: @VivekanandV: Also, negation is perfectly valid in arithmetic modulo p; it is the same as subtracting from p.  For instance, working mod 5, we have that -1 is equivalent to 4.  As such there is not a well-defined notion of a given number being "negative" or "positive".  You may want to get an elementary textbook on modular arithmetic / group theory / abstract algebra.  I don't have one to recommend offhand but most any introductory book should cover these things.

Comment: Thankyou So Much !!! I've no words to express my gratitude !!! I am always on my own in the world of Math, Cryptography & Computer Programming !!! People like you are a beacon of light in the pursuit of Knowledge !!! :) :) :) Thankyou so much !!! May God Bless You !!!  Love and Light !!! ❤ &  , I'm from India and  I posted this question on Diwali ( > 3 days ago ) !!! May God Bless You !!! 